# ERROR: modinfo: could not find module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, redhat, linux-mint

I am installing new `kernel 3.12.x` on `redhat 6` machine. Below is my steps which I followed to install the new kernel.

1. extract kernel in `/usr/src/ directory`
2. Switch to `cd /usr/src/linux-3.12.x`
3. `make menuconfig`
4. saved defaults to config file
5. `make`
6. `make modules_install`
7. `make install`

In this process I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module fuse
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module autofs4
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module target_core_iblock
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module target_core_file
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module target_core_pscsi
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module target_core_mod
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module configfs
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module 8021q
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module bnx2fc
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module fcoe
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module libfcoe
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module libfc
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module scsi_transport_fc
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module scsi_tgt
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module garp
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module stp
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module llc
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module sunrpc
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module be2iscsi
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module iscsi_boot_sysfs
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module bnx2i
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module cnic
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module uio
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module ib_iser
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module rdma_cm
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module ib_cm
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module iw_cm
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module ib_sa
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module ib_mad
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module ib_core
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module ib_addr
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module iscsi_tcp
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module libiscsi_tcp
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module libiscsi
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module scsi_transport_iscsi
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module cachefiles
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module fscache
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module ipv6
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module dm_mirror
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module dm_region_hash
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module dm_log
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module uinput
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module iTCO_wdt
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module iTCO_vendor_support
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module sg
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module coretemp
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module kvm_intel
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module kvm
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module microcode
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module serio_raw
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module pcspkr
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module i2c_i801
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module i2c_core
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module lpc_ich
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module mfd_core
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module shpchp
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module dm_mod
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module e1000e
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module i5400_edac
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module edac_core
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module i5k_amb
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module ioatdma
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module dca
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module floppy
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module ext4
ERROR: modinfo: could not find module mbcache
```

Can you guys please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a link like this :

   ln -s /usr/src/linux-3.12.x /usr/src/linux

and then proceed with the steps
Check this link : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147478/error-installinig-kernel-on-centos-from-source

2.
Also if 1 doesnt work before your Step 3 copy the **.config_XX file from the /boot directory of redhat6 to /usr/src/linux-3.12.x/.config**. Then give your step 3 as **make oldconfig**. Say no to the new features added in the new kernel. Then proceed with step 5.